# How to identify influential observations in a conditional logistic regression (clogit) model in R?

Tags: r, clogit

I have fitted a conditional logistic regression model using the clogit() function from the survival package in R, and I would like to identify the influential observations in my dataset. I have tried several functions, including influence(), influence.measures(), and dfbeta(), but none of them seem to work for clogit objects.

The influence() function returns the error message "lm object does not have a proper 'qr' component. Rank zero or should not have used lm(.., qr=FALSE)." The influence.measures() function returns the error message "*Error in UseMethod("influence.measures") : no applicable method for 'influence.measures' applied to an object of class "c('clogit', 'survmod')*". The dfbeta() function also does not seem to work.

Can anyone suggest a method for identifying influential observations in a clogit model? I would greatly appreciate any help or advice. Thank you in advance!